# JavaFX | username and password checking does not work right

Tags: java, events, javafx, fxml

I'm playing around with JavaFX and created a login form. So I want to test the inevitable, insert usernmae and password to check if correct. The problem is that it doesn't run as expected. It will always go to the else body no matter what. Code below:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML PasswordField pass;
    @FXML TextField name;
    @FXML javafx.scene.control.Button login;
    @FXML Hyperlink signup;
    @FXML Label errormessage;

    @FXML private void buttonPressed() {
        checkUser();
    }

    @FXML private void ifEnterIsPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        if (k.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
            checkUser();
    }

    @FXML private void checkUser() {
        System.out.println(name.getCharacters());
        System.out.println(pass.getCharacters());
        if (name.getCharacters().equals("Marios") && pass.getCharacters().equals("19981998")) {
            errormessage.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Access granted!");
        }
        else {
            errormessage.setText("Wrong username or password");
            System.out.println("Access denied");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I'm missing something completely obvious here or what...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use getText(), not getCharacters()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your use of the `TextField.getCharacters()` method. This isn't the same thing as calling `TextField.getText()`. Currently, for Java 10, the method `TextField.getCharacters()` returns a `StringBuilder` (which is a `CharSequence`) rather than a `String`. This is can be expected because the Javadoc states:

> Returns the character sequence backing the text field's content.

By "content" it most likely means the backing [`TextInputControl.Content`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.Content.html) and the source code of `TextField` seems to confirm this. What you want to compare, however, is the `String` contained in the `textProperty()` of the `TextField`.

Apparently, and I didn't know this (though its understandable), a `StringBuilder` *does not equals* a `String` even if they contain the same characters. Or, to put it in code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello, World!");
String s = "Hello, World!";
sb.equals(s); // FALSE
sb.toString().equals(s); // TRUE
```

So, to answer directly, change `name.getCharacters()` and `pass.getCharacters()` to `name.getText()` and `pass.getText()`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.